# Sending Bulk Mails ASP.NET not working

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to send bulk of mails but i only receive 500 mails not matter how many mails i send.I am sending mails in loop.Here is a sample.

```
foreach (EmailInfo data in emaildata.ToArray())
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

    smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);

    smtpClient.Dispose();
}
```

I am using `.net framework 4.0`.
I get this exception after 500 mails are sent

`Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: too many connections`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the server does not accept that many mails, connections in a fixed amount of time. You might want to slow things down.

Comment: Increase the time frame. Send 500 first, wait for a minute, send 500 again, continue.

Comment: I think it will help. Such restrictions are in place to avoid spamming, probably that's why you can't send that many e-mails at a time.

Comment: Well, explain him your situation and ask him could it be an anti-span measure.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely that your SMTP server is interpreting this as a spam attempt. Sending a huge amount of emails, conceptually, is simple, but anti-spam measures make things a lot more difficult. Is your service-provider aware you're trying to bulk mail? Might it be against the terms of service? These issues are a significant part of the reason why bulk-mailing services like MailChimp exist.

P.S. Be very mindful of trying workarounds to get this working too, if you keep pushing this you're liable to get your account banned or server black-listed.

Comment: Is your network administrator responsible for the SMTP server you're connecting to, or is it just a proxy? Have you taken steps to ensure your actions will not result in anti-spam measures? This is more than just a technical issue, it's a legal / terms of service one, and if you aren't careful you could make some much bigger problems.

Comment: Running your own server, as far as I see it, means you could get yourself into even bigger trouble. If you've got an SMTP server with an ISP, maybe they ban your account, you plead your case, promise to be good and they un-ban you. But if you're running your own server, the greater threat is receiving servers blacklisting your server, potentially without you even realising. An example of one such black-list : http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/check_banned_ip.php

Comment: i will try to discuss with my manager and network administrator.